# MVC Shared Layout Parameter to Logoff

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use a shared layout and I am trying to pass the current location to the logoff method, but I'm not sure how to do it.  I've tried: Request.Url.OriginalString, Request.Url.Scheme and in the logoff method the parameter type I put the parameter type as string but it isn't working.  Anyone have any idea?

Log Off Button on my layout page

```
<a onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Logoff", "Account", "Request.Url.Scheme")'"><span class="logOffSpan">Sign Out</span

public ActionResult LogOff(string url)
    {
        var local = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["local"]);
        if (local)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        }
        else
        {
            CasAuthentication.SingleSignOut();
        }

        Session.Clear();
        return to Redirect("Some Method","Some Controller");//I want the user to just return to whatever page they were just on when they clicked log off
    }
```

Comment: Share the relevant code and your expected behavior

Comment: I updated my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` to get the absolute URL of the current page.

Then you can use this overload of `@Url.Action` method which takes a `RouteValueDictionary` object as third parameter to build the route params / querystrings.

```
public virtual string Action (string actionName, 
                              string controllerName, 
                              RouteValueDictionary routeValues);
```

So your view code will be

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Logoff", "Account", new { url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri })">
    <span class="logOffSpan">Sign Out</span>
</a>
```

This will basically generate the anhcor tag with the `href` attribute value set to `/Account/Logogg?url={yourCurrentPageUrl}`, where `{yourCurrentPageUrl}` will be replaced with your current page URL.

Now in your action method you can use the `Redirect` method  with this aboslute URL value which will be available in your `url` parameter.

```
public ActionResult LogOff(string url)
{
    // Your existing logic

    return Redirect(url);
}
```